# Unix: Remove the filename, get only the extension and rename the extension using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have lot filenames which have this kind format:

```
118-edorf.sum.fil
118-edorf.sum.fil_1
118-edorf.sum.fil_11
```

i want to remove 118-edorf.sum. from the filename and get only the extension , fil , fil_1 and fil_11 and rename it to asc, asc_1 and asc_11.

So far, i can only remove 118-edorf.sum. using

```
sed 's/.*\.//'
```

The result will be

```
fil
fil_1
fil_11
```

So, how to rename it to

```
asc
asc_1
asc_11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your solution only add additional substitution

```
sed 's/^.*\.//; s/fil/asc/'
```

To rename all files in directory using that criteria

```
rename 's/^.*\.//; s/fil/asc/' *
```

note: this rename command is untested

Comment: Would be worth explaining what this command does and why it works.

Comment: Op who is unresponsive gives as example strings situation not filenames. For filenames manipulation correct command is rename.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this zsh foreach loop. Foreach can be somewhat slow for many files. You can also remove the echo statements for less noisier output.

```
foreach C (`ls 118-edorf.sum.fil*`)
    f2=`echo $C|cut -d "." -f 3|cut -s -d "_" -f 2`
    if [ "${f2}" -eq "" ]; then
        echo "no underscore"
        mv $C asc
    elif
    echo "_${f2}"
    mv $C "asc_${f2}"
end
```

Comment: Note that parsing the output of `ls` like that is dangerous (if the file names contain spaces — or other special characters — it usually doesn't give you the result you want).  In context, `foreach C ( 118-edorf.sum.fil* )` would probably do the same job (I'm guessing; not actually a `zsh` user).  And in a POSIX-like shell, you'd use `for C in 118-edorf.sum.fil*` and the would definitely work.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I have tried that many times. :-) Then I would resort to perl, python, ruby etc. that handles filenames with spaces much better.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*\.([^_]*(.*))/mv \1 asc\2/e' file
```

Use an evaluated substitution command. The substitution removes everything upto the last `.` and retains everything thereafter as the first backreference.  Everything following the first `_` within that backreference is also retained as the second backreference. The RHS of the substitution command the forms a `mv` commmand using the parts from the LHS.

If your sed does not have the `e` command/flag, use:

```
sed 's/.*\.\([^_]*\(.*\)\)/mv \1 asc\2/' file | shell
```

It might be safer to use:

```
sed -r 's/.*\.(fil(.*))/mv \1 asc\2/e' file
```